# Stopping stacktrace on a JOptionPane

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, stack-trace, joptionpane

I am trying to stop a stacktrace which doesn't seem to be listening to my null check.

```
          if(amountEntered != null){

                   amntEntered = Double.parseDouble(amountEntered);       
            }

            else if(amountEntered != ""){

                amntEntered = Double.parseDouble(amountEntered);
            }

            else if((amountEntered == null || amountEntered == "")){
             System.out.print("");    
            }
```

With this code, it should stop the stacktrace which executes when I try and cancel out of the JOptionPane (amountEntered is the variable in which the JOptionPane is assigned to) -- amntEntered is the double equivelent.

Comment: [How to compare Strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is a bit off, first off, in Java `String`s are compared using `equals(..)`:

```
if(amountEntered != null){
      amntEntered = Double.parseDouble(amountEntered);  
      // Because you are comparing amountEntered to "" and you check if it's null
      //I assume it is of type String which means that you can't cast it to a double.
}else if(!amountEntered.equals("")){ 
        // if it gets past the first check
        // it means that amountEntered is null and this will produce a NullPointerException
    amntEntered = Double.parseDouble(amountEntered);
}else if((amountEntered == null || amountEntered.equals(""))){
        // Here if amountEntered is null, the second check will
        // still be executed and will produce a NullPointerException
        // When you use || both the check before || and after || are executed
    System.out.print("");    
}
```

Here is how you can perform the check and deal with any `Exception`s:

```
if(amountEntered != null && !amountEntered.isEmpty()){
   try{
      someDoubleVariable = Double.parseDouble(amountEntered);
   }catch(NumberFormatException e){
      someDoubleVariable = 0;
      e.printStackTrace()
   }
}else if(amountEntered==null || (amountEntered!=null && amountEntered.isEmpty())){
     someDoubleVariable = 0;
}
```

In this example, because I'm using `&&` the condition checking will stop as soon as one of them is `false` which means that in the last `else if` if `amountEntered` is null `amountEntered.isEmpty()` will not be executed

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing string so instead of `amountEntered != ""` you should be using

```
!amountEntered.equals("");
```

this applies *whenever you want to compare strings* in `Java`...

but ***`especially`*** for equality to null try `string == null`

Comment: I've tried the .equals method and it's still doing the same thing. After putting it in a try catch block it seems to have fixed parted of the issue on the 'OK' button, but the 'Cancel' button is still producing a stack-trace.

Comment: try the `==` for `null` and the `equals` for the other strings... and tell me if it works